# How do I format a date pulled from a database?

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2010

I am trying to pull a date from database and putting it on a webpage with the below code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TravelDate") %>' /><br /><br />
```

It pulls the date with no problem, but when it shows up on the page, no matter how it is formatted in the database, it seems to want to always display the date as "6/17/2013 12:00:00am". Is there something I'm missing in the VS portion that I have to use to format the date? I'd prefer "June 17, 2013", but the only option close to that in Access is where it adds the day of the week in front of it. Getting rid of the time is important.

Comment: <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TravelDate") %>' /><br /><br />
That's the code that's supposed to show up above.

Comment: i think it has something to do with setting our label to only display a date in a specific format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:Label ID="txtDate" Width="65px" runat="server" Font-Size="8.5pt" ForeColor="#000f9f"
                                                            Text='<%# Eval("How_date","{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: That gave me exactly what I needed. Thanks Senthil!

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract like the field like this:

```
Expr1:Format([Field Name],"DD/MM/YYYY")
```

or

If it's a text field then you can use the `string function left() or right()` to get the date. `Expr1:Left([Field Name],10)`

Comment: That will pull the date from the database? Also, will that format it like this: June 17, 2013?

Comment: Yes that will pull it from the database.  Sorry it will pull as 17/07/2013  Do you have any options on where you are putting it? Or is it just a straight push?

Comment: It can work like that also. I can go with that. I guess I'm not certain what you mean by your question, but the date is part of an ItemTemplate element.

Comment: Also, I just tried putting the code you suggested in the Eval() function, as that where I assumed it went, and it gave me a "tag not well formed error."

Comment: Did you replace FIELD NAME with TRAVEL DATE in the above code?  I was asking if the place you were placing the data had any display options...was not familiar with where it was going.  No matter how you format the display of the data in MS Access it doesnt actually change the way the data is stored so when you go with a straight extraction the data is still in the long datetime format even if you tell it to only show the short date.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Here is the code with your suggested modification:

    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval('Expr1:Format([TravelDate],"DD/MM/YYYY")') %>' /><br /><br />

Comment: And did I answer your question about where the date is going?

Comment: Somewhat.  I am not familiar with asp.net  More expertise with the database side.  What does Label3 refer to?  I am thinking it does not write a direct query on the table in the database so maybe you need to write a query to change the date to the format with that code and then tell the program to display the query results vs. the table.  Unless you have any options on changing how the date goes into the database.

Comment: Oh dear, now when I tried to put it back to the way it was, I get the error that the table is already opened exclusively.

Comment: This site is telling me to avoid extended discussion in comments. How do we proceed?

Comment: Check this site out and see if it can help with the database lock issue  http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-access/991554-table-already-opened-exclusively.html

Comment: I just closed my database (which I've had open whenever I edit my website generally speaking. Probably a bad idea, but it has been working) and it started working again.

ID is a property of the element "asp:Label", Label3 defines the ID property of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the single quotation mark '' after the property text of the TextBox.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("TravelDate", "{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}") %> /><br /><br />
```